# Struggling to Use an Array of Objects in a Method

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Let me preface this by saying that my knowledge when it comes to coding in general is very lackluster.

I've begun working on a code that creates a high score table, as of right now only random numbers show up but that's besides the point.  I decided to use a class to practice, and I'm having trouble with using an array of objects in a function.

Class contains 2 variables, first one stores the score as an int, second stores the names as a string but the string isn't exactly relevant to my question.

```
class Table
{
public:
    int m_score = 0;
    string m_name = { " " };
    void randomizeScores(Table position[], int amount);
};

int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    Table position[size];

    /* Here seems to be the problem
       Replacing position.randomizeScores with Replacing position->randomizeScores makes it work
       and I have no idea why.  Which is what i'd like to find out*/

    position.randomizeScores(position, size);
}

void Table::randomizeScores(Table position[], int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        position[i].m_score = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much folks!

Comment: You can't call a member function on an array of objects. You need to call it on a single object, or you need to make it `static` for this to work. That's why using `->` works, because you are invoking it on the first object in the array.

Comment: Ohh, i see, thanks.  Just to clarify, ```->``` only works on the first object of the array?

Comment: No, you could do `(&position[3])->randomizeScores(position, size);` if you wanted to, but `position` is a pointer to `position[0]`, that's why it will use the first.

Comment: @Yuty06 Yes, with `->`, the array decays to a pointer to its first element, which is then dereferenced and has its method called.  It's the same as using `->` to access a member through any other pointer.

Comment: You can also not make `randomizeScores` a member function and it would work fine. Remove `position.randomizeScores(position, size);` from your class and just declare `void randomizeScores(Table position[], int amount)` below it. and call `randomizeScores(position, size);` in `main()`. (P.S., you need to call `srand();` once before your first call to `rand()` -- otherwise, things are not very random -- which I know isn't the main point, but don't overlook it if you actually want random values...)

Comment: use std::vector instaed of old fashoined arrays (jeez its ages since i typed the universal c++ answer)